# PowerShell: Replace help file viewer

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell all help files open in more. There I can only scroll with the Return key. When I pipe a command like `man ls -full | less` I can see the help file in less and scroll with `j` and `k`. Is there a way to open help pages in less by default, so I don't have to type `| less` after each command that is outputting text?

Also is there a way to scroll in less using the mousewheel like in linux bash man pages? Or is that something that the terminal does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `less` as the default pager by setting an alias.

```
Set-Alias more less
```

Comment: Works great, but it seems like a hack to me. Isn't there a way to set the default viewer somewhere? It makes me feel uneasy that the help file viewer "thinks" it uses more, when it actually uses less. ;-)